# ionicBootstrap not importing in app.component.ts ionic v2.1.18

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi Everyone, 
                     My name is Kris Chery. I am new to ionic  and am using  version 2.1.18. I have been following this tutorial which I think is very insightful about the powers of ionic.
https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/

I am stuck at the ionicBootstrap implementation. For now its a simple service that needs to display a message but for some reason. I can't seem to import ionic Bootstrap it is saying that ionicBoostrap wasn't exported from node modules.

This is  information is imperative for me to my dream app. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I have done a number or research on the matter but none led to a good explanation on how to fix it or to implement it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using that tutorial and using the official Angular docs instead. That was written back in July. Back then Angular 2 was only in RC phase and Ionic 2 was still in beta. A lot has changed since then.

You don't want to use bootstrapping for this, your app already does it's bootstrapping in app.ts. Instead in app.module.ts you can import other module and declare providers.

Angular 2 Tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/
Bootstrapping and modules: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#bootstrap

Comment: Thank you. I did the heroes app yesterday. I was looking to this tutorial to point how to put it all together in ionic. Much appreciated. If you do have something with ionic v2 that you think will help me make a smooth transition from angular 2 (Hero to tutorial) to ionic 2. Please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately not a whole lot. But other than having to use the nav controller instead of routes, Ionic 2 is just Angular 2, but with it's own css and directives. If you know Angular 2 fairly well you should be able to just jump into Ionic 2 with it's docs.