# Global instance of provider in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, service, ionic3

I have a provider that has to be always up when the app is running to watch for the network connection status.

So according to that [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/) I have added the class to my  `app.module.ts` file to make it a *global instance*. So as far as I understand it, the service should be up when the app initializes it's root component (thus `app.module.ts`).

**Problem**: The provider gets not called until a specific page of the app imports and uses it.

In the mentioned tutorial the `provider` is imported like that:

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [TestProvider]);
```

Unfortunately that does not work for me. That [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42500528/4125633) says that this quite new tutorial is outdated.

**Question**: How could I use `providers` in `Ionic 3` that they are available as *one instance* after launching the application?

My app.module.ts:

```
import { NetworkConnectionProvider } from '../providers/networkconnection/networkconnection';
// (...)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    // (...)
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ionicGalleryModal.GalleryModalModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    IonicApp
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    // (...)
  ],
  providers: [
    // (...)
    NetworkConnectionProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';


@Injectable()
export class NetworkConnectionProvider {
  private TAG = "NetworkConnectionProvider ";

  private isConnectedToInternet: Boolean;

  constructor(
    public http: Http,
    public network: Network
    ) {

    this.isConnectedToInternet = true;

    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'network was disconnected.');
      this.isConnectedToInternet = false;
    });

    // watch network for a connection
    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');
      this.isConnectedToInternet = true;

      // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
      // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
      // prior to doing any api requests as well.
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
          console.log(this.TAG + 'wifi connection available');
        }
      }, 3000);
    });

    console.log('Hello NetworkConnectionProvider');
  }

  public subscribeOnConnect() {
    return this.network.onConnect();
  }

  public isConnected(): Boolean{
    return this.isConnectedToInternet;
  }

  public getConnectionType(): string {
    return this.network.type;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve that the app creates an instance of a provider on launching (what makes sense for a network provider that watches the network status ) simply add the provider to the `app.module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    NetworkConnectionProvider
  ]
```

After that add it to the constructor of `app.component.ts`

```
constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private sideMenuService: SideMenuService,
    network: NetworkConnectionProvider
  ) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

    // other stuff
  }
```

Every time that provider is imported and used later on in the app it will be the same instance.

Comment: this means we further don't need to call function of checking network anywhere in the app

Answer (score 0):

You have done it wrong with latest `Ionic 3` and `CLI`.It was an old method and now outdated.

Hope you're using latest `CLI`.Then it is automatic mostly.

```
ionic generate provider SubscribeTopic
```

It'll automatically add `SubscribeTopic` into `providers` array in the `app.module.ts`

**Note:** This is just an example.Please adjust it according to your use case.

*app.module.ts*

```
providers: [
  //other providers here
  SubscribeTopic //here
]
```

After that, you need to inject it into your page as shown below.

*yourPage.ts*

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private subscribeTopic : SubscribeTopic ) {

  }
```

That is it.You can refer [**this article**](https://www.djamware.com/post/58e657b680aca764ec903c2d/ionic-3-and-angular-4-mobile-app-example) too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call that provider at least once, Call that provider in your home.ts file

```
import { NetworkConnectionProvider } from '../Your-Path';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public netprovider : NetworkConnectionProvider ) {
   netprovider.activateNetwork();
}
```

create a activateNetwork() function in your provider.

In your provider file:

```
activateNetwork(){
   let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log(this.TAG + 'network was disconnected.');
  this.isConnectedToInternet = false;
});

// watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');
  this.isConnectedToInternet = true;

  // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
  // before we determine the connection type. Might need to wait.
  // prior to doing any api requests as well.
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
      console.log(this.TAG + 'wifi connection available');
    }
  }, 3000);
});

}
```